# How to create SQL query from linq query

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, vb.net, linq

I have a linq query like this:
(`Docs` is a `DbSet(Of Blahblah)` in code-first pattern of EF)

```
Dim Docs = (from doc in db.Docs where Doc.Order = 10)
```

it will be translated to something like this:

```
SELECT Ex.Order, Ex.Name, Ex.ModifyDate FROM Doc AS Ex
WHERE Ex.Order = @p0
```

it's ok, but I want this query to be translated to something else. this is because my SELECT command is not a common select and It's NOT possible to map select to an stored procedure!

for example, I want my linq query above be translated to something like this:

```
SELECT Ex.Order, Ex.Name FROM GetRecordsOf(Doc)
```

while the `GetRecordsOf(tbl)` is a sql table valued function wich returns specific rows of my `Doc` Table.

Now the question is

**How Can I Control The Process Of Translating LINQ to SQL Statements**
or basically **What Can I Do For this?**

Comment: Does this help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386954(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: GREAT THANKS MAN! That's it. sometime things can be done more easily than we think!